# What feature to use when trying to display the grid with text values and urls in sharepoint?

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I am new to sharepoint 2010 and therefore, not sure what feature to use to make the following:
I am trying to create some sort of grid with text values as column headers and rows containing URL links but named with some text for clarity's sake.
For example:

Header1
link1
link2
I want to have multiple headers and rows like that.

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might find looking at a control called the listview using itemTemplate would be benificial. It can allow you to create a look and feel like a business card or a very simple row

Have a look here they show some of the formats they have done

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mikeormond/archive/2008/01/23/some-asp-net-3-5-listview-control-examples.aspx

Comment: Hello Truezplaya,
what about just creating a list with multiple columns in sharepoint?
Is this possible?

Comment: I was assuming that you had this data stored within a SharePoint list somewhere and you just wnated to display it in a nice way. If you just want to store the data, Create a custom list by navigating to Site actions -> More Options -> Custom list and add you columns via list settings.  You may find this video informative http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GmVy5roiKzg